# How to export Excel spreadsheets to XML, but attributes have been instead elements?

Tags: xml, excel

I save a spreadsheets from Excel to XML in this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<companies>
<company>
<employee>
<code>1</code>
<name/>
<street>14th street</street>
<houseno>1</houseno>
<areacode>1050 DD</areacode>
<place>NoWhere</place>
<phone>0100 987654</phone>
</employee>
</company>
</companies>
```

But I need this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<companies>
<company>
<employee code="1" name="" street="14th street"  houseno="1" areacode="1050 DD" place="NoWhere" phone="0100 987654">
</employee>
</company>
</companies>
```

Tell me please how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet would do it ([try it here](http://www.shell-tools.net/index.php?op=xslt) with your sample XML).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="employee/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now it depends onyour environment how you can use it. There are several tools and libraries available that provide XSLT support.

Answer (score 1):

You XSLT to transform your XML data.